# how can i check the condition in mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

table1

Id, name, address

table2
id, city, village

I want to check the if in table1 same id param exist then return id, city village in table2 how can i write sql query for the same..

Please help

Comment: suppose I have in table1

id   name   address
1    v2         sonam

and table2

id  city  village
1   m2   c2

I want to output id 1 city m2 village c2

Comment: Priya. Priya. Priya.

Comment: Hi Danish my asking question limit over so what is the procedure for next can you please let me know

Comment: I didn't get question. can you please explain me @Priya.

Comment: You have reached your question limit stackoverflow saying when i am invoking ask question......... ;(

Comment: Try answering few questions.. earn reputation. you will be able to question.

Comment: ohhhhhhh.. tough one

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly , your id form table1 is a foreign key in table2 , and if you want to fetch all the data , you should use a query like this one:

"select name, address, city, village from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id

I am not sure that this is what you want, if you can be more specific maybe I can help you